# Mockit is failing at initialization when used in maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

Getting below error for my tests. I am using an internal jar which has mockit 1.0 but as i was getting error of require lower jvm. Hence added below dependency so that i can force maven to use below version but now getting below error.

Note: This workaround worked in windows but now not working in mac

```
Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
```

[ERROR] java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.testng.ITestNGListener: Provider mockit.integration.testng.Initializer could not be instantiated

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that i had one company built jar dependency in my Pom which had older version of Jmockit. I solved it by adding exclusion in my pom while adding that dependency in my POM